# Return localized success/error message from PayFlow

Tags: paypal, localization, payflowpro

I'm making the following call using PayPal's PayFlow pro SDK.

```
SaleTransaction sTrans = new SaleTransaction( user, connection, inv, card, PayflowUtility.getRequestId() );
Response resp = sTrans.submitTransaction();
```

All error messages are returned in English.
Is it possible to pass a parameter to return response messages in another language?

If not, I'll use the returned error code and create some resource bundle messages per language.

Answer (score 0):

Payflow responses are not localized.